# Lazy loading with uitableview with contentoffset in a chat application

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, lazy-loading

I am developing a chat application , I want to implement lazy loading with an array of model data . The issue is that I cannot set proper uitableview content offset as I am populating the array while my tableview scroll position is less than say 100-200. These are the thing which I have in hand : **previous offset before table reload , previous content size before table reload and new contentsize after table reload** . This is a chat application so I am scrolling from top to bottom like other chat application (whatsapp etc).

**Here is the code for scrollviewdidscroll :**

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if (scrollView == self.tblMessage){
            if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 200.0 && isLoadingMore){
                count = count + 30
                let prevOffset = self.tblMessage.contentOffset
                let prevContSize = self.tblMessage.contentSize
                self.getDateWiseMessagesFromLocalDB()
                let newOffset = self.tblMessage.contentSize.height - prevContSize.height + 200 + self.tblMessage.frame.height
                self.tblMessage.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: newOffset), animated: false)
                isLoadingMore = false
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Please add some code so that your question would be more clear.

Comment: Added the code @ArunKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer , the only thing that needed change was the newOffset. Set it to

```
let newOffset = self.tblMessage.contentSize.height - prevContSize.height + self.tblMessage.frame.height
```